# How to display a popup message on record save

Tags: popup

When a user edits the value of a custom field business_sector__c on Opportunity using a standard page in Classic UI and clicks 'Save', I want to pop up a message reminding them that they need to review a field value on Opportunity Products.  The popup should just have an 'OK' button that closes it.

What is the recommended approach for this?

Thanks.

Comment: The popup is required when the field value is changed.  The value that it is changed to does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are cool with replacing the edit button functionality to a custom vf pgae then I think we can achieve this.

In below example, i have a field leadSource on opportunity. if someone clicks edit on an opportunity and changes value of leadSource, a pop up will come
step1: create a page which uses standardController=opportunity.

**VF PAGE:**

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="opportunity" extensions="testEditOppController" standardStylesheets="true" sidebar="true" showHeader="true">
<apex:form>
    <apex:outputPanel id='testPanel'>
        <script>
        function funcTest(varA){
            if(varA){
                alert('LEAD SOURCE IS CHANGED');
            }
            redirectToDetailPage();
        }
        </script>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:actionFunction name="doSave" rerender="testPanel" action="{!test}" oncomplete="funcTest('{!isChanged}'); "/>
    <apex:actionFunction name="redirectToDetailPage" action="{!redirectMethod}"/>
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Opportunity Information" collapsible="false">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.LeadSource  }" style="height: 20px"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.closeDate}" style="height: 20px"/>
                <div  style="text-align:center;">   
                    <apex:commandButton onclick="doSave();" 
                                        oncomplete="funcTest()" value="Save"/>
                </div>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel> 
</apex:form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class testEditOppController {
@TestVisible private final opportunity opp;
    public ApexPages.StandardController stdCon;
    public boolean isChanged{get;set;}
    public string callfunc{get;set;}
    public opportunity currentOpp{get;set;}

    public testEditOppController(ApexPages.StandardController stdCon){
        this.opp=(opportunity)stdCon.getRecord();
        currentopp=[select leadSource from opportunity where id=:this.opp.id limit 1];
    }  
    public void test(){
        if(currentOpp.LeadSource!=this.opp.LeadSource){
            isChanged=true;
        }
        update this.opp;
    }
    public pagereference redirectMethod(){
        PageReference pageRef=new PageReference('/' + this.opp.id);
        return pageRef;
    }
}
```

On opportunity, for edit button, override with the visual force page you created above.